# Is it possible to create a drawer menu in react native router flux?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-router-flux

React native router flux is made on top of react navigation. Here - https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux#v4-features - said that drawer supported. But I can't find any information about how can I do this?
Can anyone show example?

```
<Scene key="authentication">

    <Scene key="page1" component={Page1} title="Page1"/>
    <Scene key="page2" component={Page2} title="Page2" />

    <Drawer
        hideNavBar
        key="drawer"
        drawerWidth={300}
        contentComponent={ContentComp}
        >
        <Scene key="side" component={DrawerMenu} title="Menu" />
    </Drawer>

</Scene>
```

What next? There is no anything on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [API](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#drawer-drawer-or-scene-drawer). Just declare a `<Drawer>` route in your routes declaration

Comment: Hunaid Hassan, I've updated the question. I looked at the API, but can't make it work.

Comment: Your `Drawer` component should have a `contentComponent ` prop. Try this.

Comment: Done. Nothing changed. I can't understand how it works. It should wrap all scenes where you want side menu to be able?

Comment: What are stacks, what are scenes? What is different between wrapping by stacks and scenes (drawer is just a syntax sugar)? Is there any normal description of logic, not just api description?

Comment: Scene is a screen, Stack is a group of screens with their own navigator. Stacks are used to create nested navigators

Comment: A `Drawer` is a `Scene` so you can refer to Scene API docs mentioned by @HunaidHassan